# Solving a congruence using primitive roots

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, primitive-roots

Suppose we know that $3$ is a primitive root of $17$.

How can that help us solving $7^x \equiv 6 \pmod {17}$?

Comment: You could start by finding $a$ and $b$ with $3^a\equiv 7$ and $3^b\equiv 6\pmod{17}$.

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a shot

Comment: You can use [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms) for a systematic approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use  [Discrete Logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html) wrt primitive root $3\pmod{17},$

$x$ind$_37\equiv$ind$_3(2\cdot3)\pmod{\phi(17)}\equiv$ind$_32+1$

Now $3^3\equiv10\pmod{17},3^5\equiv9\cdot10\equiv5\implies7\equiv5^{-1}\equiv3^{-5}\equiv3^{16-5}$

$2\equiv(-1)3\cdot5\pmod{17}\equiv3^{8+1+5}$ as $3$ is a primitive root, $3^{(17-1)/2}\equiv-1\pmod{17}$

$\implies11x\equiv14+1\pmod{16}\equiv-1$

$\implies3\cdot11x\equiv-1\cdot3\pmod{16}$

$\iff x\equiv-3\equiv13\pmod{16}$